# XAMARIN FORM : How to programmatically open page and scroll down and hightlight viewcell of listview when open firebase notification

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have create app in which user assign a task to other user, when user assign a task the other use get notification that you have been assigned a new task this is my code

```
 public void NewTaskNotification()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = "-1";
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AAAAHiXg3GM:APA91bFhpVU5meuhVtbHUzIgd7Ualwdi8PROKbXIf0Y_tU9sxI71vPdiInOpRgribAUuqpuqn5hmaZV7ZwQTGv2KKERsKGYOwjkwZIqssWYiYNh7IrjhfnBR0XJj7t-GW7GqvEHVs0Q"));
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "129484512355"));
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                var payload = new
                {
                    to = device_token.Text,
                    priority = "high",
                    content_available = true,
                    notification = new
                    {

                        body = "You have been assigned a new task " + "(" + TaskName.Text + ") by " + EmployeeName.Text,
                        title = "New Task",
                        icon = "Icon.png"
                    },
                    data = new
                    {
                        open_page = "NewTask",
                        new_task="newNotification",
                    },

                };
```

App.cs

```
  protected override void OnStart()
        {
  CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
                {
                    if (p.Data["open_page"].ToString() == "NewTask")

                    {
                        //var mdMasterPage = new MainPage { Title = "master page" };
                        //var mdp = new MasterDetailPage();
                        //mdp.Master = mdMasterPage;
                        //mdp.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ToDo)));
                        //Application.Current.MainPage = mdp;

                        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedMainPage())
                        {
                            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#C6488D"),
                            BarTextColor = Color.White
                        };
                    }
```

currenly when i open notification its just open the page and dont hit the speicific row of listview which is link to this notification i need to solve this issue but i am stuck how to do that

Comment: Assuming the ListView is contained in the TabbedMainPage? And the ListvView is populated and contains a row/object that you need to scroll to?

Comment: yes listview is in tabbed page, so basically what i am doing now is to open tabbed page when open notification, which is working fine, but its not a good practice as i want i want is when user open notification it should hit the specific row which is link to that notification for example user get notificaiton that u have been assigned to "Task1", now this Task 1 will be in listview, so when user open notification it should hightlight row of task1 in listview

Comment: Either obtain the ListView reference from the TabbedMainPage instance that you create and scroll to the proper row from the `OnNotificationOpened` or create a new constructor on TabbedMainPage and pass it the information needed to scroll to the correct row...

Comment: thats what i am asking how to scroll down to correct row?

Comment: `ScrollTo` method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `ScrollTo`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms), you can specify the item that you want to scroll into.